# Allocating int storage?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'm a a beginner to C.

```
main() {    
   int *a-ptr = (int *)malloc(int); 
   *a-ptr = 5;
   printf(“%d”, *a-ptr);
}
```

The question is: is this guaranteed to print 5?

The answer is : NO, for two reasons:

- you can't use "-" in the names of variables
- "you didn't allocate int storage"

I don't understand that second point. Isn't the storage allocated  with this line? 
 
`int *a-ptr = (int *)malloc(int);`

Comment: Maybe, it's hard to tell. What is `malloc(int)` supposed to mean?

Comment: This program is guaranteed not to print 5.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: the behaviour of an ill-formed program that the implementation chooses to accept anyway is entirely implementation-defined. So it's not *guaranteed* not to do anything ;-)

Comment: Actually I say "implementation-defined": it might still be unspecified or undefined. The compiler only defines the effect of the extension that causes it to accept the program, it doesn't have to somehow document all unrelated UB that the programmer might have put in there.

Comment: @SteveJessop:  Good point.  I forgot that C does not have the strict "well-formedness" requirements that C++ has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    main() {    // wrong. Should return int
int main() {    // better

int *a-ptr =  //wrong. no dashes in variable names
int *a_ptr =  // better, use underscores if you want to have multiparted names

(int *)malloc(int); // wrong. Don't typecast the return of malloc(), also it takes a 
                    // size, not a type
malloc(sizeof(int)); // better, you want enought memory for the sizeof 1 int
```

So a better version of your code would be:

```
int main() {    
   int *a_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
   *a_ptr = 5;
   printf("%d", *a_ptr);
   free(a_ptr); // When you're done using memory allocated with malloc, free it
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: MUST `main` return an int? The simple K&R examples I've seen have it as `main()`.

Comment: Ah, I see with C99, I get `warning: return type defaults to ‘int’`. With regular gcc, no warning and a working program. When did this convention come about?

Comment: @user1850672 - The examples you're using are probably old, but the C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) standard says:`The int return type may not be omitted.`

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` accepts a size, not a type. You would need to do `malloc(sizeof(int))`.

Comment: Rather `malloc(sizeof *aptr)`...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid for a number of reasons, and would not compile.

1. `a-ptr` is an invalid variable name. `-` is not allowed in a name,
   use `a_ptr` instead (or whatever)
2. `malloc` does not take a type. It takes a size (in bytes) to
   allocate.
3. Be sure to use straight quotes `"` instead of the curly quotes you
   used.

Correct code would look like this:

```
int main() {
    int *aptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *aptr = 5;
    printf("%d", *aptr);

    return 0;
}
```

(The cast from `malloc` to `int *` may be optional, depending on your compiler.)

Comment: there are places here where you can be shot since you dared `main()` instead of `main(void)` or `main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: @ShinTakezou I'm not familiar with the intricacies of C - can you please explain or provide a link?

Comment: I was just making an irony on me since I sometimes got "attacked" (correctly, don't get me wrong) for the use of `int main()` (which I have my reason to prefer against any reasonability) instead of `int main(void)`. Simply the fact is that the standard (at least, C99 std) won't consider `int main()` correct; that is syntactically allowed (for historical reason?) but, according to someone, it should be removed (or the std needs to be changed in the other way allowing `int main()` to really mean `int main(void)`, while currently they differ...). Forget it, or search SO for the proto for main:)

Comment: @ShinTakezou Gotcha, some convoluted standards thing :) Thanks.

Comment: @Shin I originally had it in there, but decided to take it out at the last minute since it'll just confuse the poor fellow :)

Comment: it's what I do everytime too, but noone gets it! :)